# Django DRF REST Put method not updating anything

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, put

In Django PUT request when I am updating value of location and hours per week, the PUT request returns exact same values and did not update anything.

Below is my code,

**url**

```
url(
r'^api/availability', views.AvailabilityAPIView.as_view(),name='api_availability'
)
```

**models**

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    # Skill model which contains trainer's skill details
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    locations = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    hours_per_week = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.locations + "|" + str(self.hours_per_week)
```

**serializer**

```
class AvailabilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Availability
        fields = ['user', 'locations', 'hours_per_week']
```

**views**

```
class AvailabilityAPIView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)

    def get(self, request):
        availability = Availability.objects.all()
        serializer = AvailabilitySerializer(availability, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request):
        serializer = AvailabilitySerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Please help to understand what I am doing wrong. Do I need to pass PK from url and update the specific one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of your `Availability` model.

```
def put(self, request):
        instance = Availability.objects.get(user=request.user)
        serializer = AvailabilitySerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Just my 2 cents: `partial` shouldn't be `True` for a `PUT` request, it is meant for `PATCH` request type. Actually that's the biggest difference between purposes of `PUT` and `PATCH` request types.